# How to dynamically add and use edit texts in android?

Tags: java, android

What I'm wanting to do is use the user's input to determine the size of a matrix, then create the appropriate amount of edit texts for them to fill out the elements. I think I know how to add in new edit texts dynamically, but I don't know how to address them, because they have no id since they are being made dynamically.

Comment: What's stopping you to give them some chosen ids when you build them?

Comment: use setId() for your EditText

Answer (score 2):

you can set the index of the EditText as id.

```
for(int i=0;i<max;i++){
    EditText et=new ExitText(this);
    //.........
    et.setId(i);
}
```

And call `findViewById(0);` and so on